# Setting an Interval for a retrieving conversation using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to add a `setInterval` on my function to make it retrieve my conversation automatically after a user was selected.

Here is what I have so far:

```
stats_li.find("a").on("click", function() {
    $('.chatBox input[type="hidden"]').attr('value', $(this).data("userid"));
    var user = $(this).data("usernem");
    var uid = $(this).data("suid");
    var rid = $(this).data("userid"),
        data = {
            chat: uid,
            rid: rid,
            name: user
        };
    id = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlechat.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(result) {
                $("#clog").empty();
                $.each(result, function(rowKey, row) {

                    $("#clog").append('<p ><h4>' + row.username + ':</h4>' + row.message_content + '</p>');

                });
                clearInterval(id);
            }
        })
    }, 200);
});
```

My problem is this script loads `http://localhost/chat/includes/handlechat.php?chat=2&rid=1&name=a.b` depending on the number of conversation I have on my database.

- How can I make it load only once for all the conversation inside my database?
- How can I run my interval again after it's done loading?
- Is it advisable to use `setInterval` for my chat application?

Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: In general using an interval here is bad in terms of async processing - instead setting a new timeout in the success callback is the way to go

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to clear the interval once the first response has arrived?

Comment: @Bergi My thinking is that if I clear the Interval the whole function will refresh again because Its inside a script where It checks if a user has logged on(similar to facebook) am I wrong on my assumptions? Sorry I'm a noob on javascript =(

Comment: No, clearing the interval does stop the repeated execution, instead of restarting the circle.

Comment: @Bergi so what can you suggest on my prob?? Please I need help =(

Comment: Use something like `function go() { clearTimeout(id); $.ajax(…).done(function(result) { …; id=setTimeout(go, 1000); }); } go();`

Comment: Ok I'll try it out now.. thnx =)